# How to change django wagtail's admin logo

Tags: python, django, templates, wagtail

I am working on a small project and I thought I'd give [wagtail](http://wagtail.io/) a try. I am now wondering how I could change wagtail's admin logo in the sidebar (top left image on the picture bellow).

[image: github wagtail image]

I could change `/static/wagtailadmin/images/wagtail-logo.svg` directly but it'd be wrong ;).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wagtail already provide the solution in the official documentation using [django-overextends](https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-overextends):

To replace the default logo, create a template file `your_app/templates/wagtailadmin/base.html` that overrides the block branding_logo as follow:

```html
{% overextends "wagtailadmin/base.html" %}

{% block branding_logo %}
    <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/custom-logo.svg" alt="Custom Project" width="80" />
{% endblock %}
```

Check [Wagtail Custom branding](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.3.1/advanced_topics/customisation/branding.html) for more details.

---

### (Edit Dec - 2020)

Note: In the latests versions of Wagtail `django-overextends` is not needed anymore. It uses now the default `extends` tag of `Django` templates. [Consult the docs](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.11.3/advanced_topics/customisation/admin_templates.html) for more information

Comment: Cool, this documentation was added on `v1.0` and wasn't released at the time of writing question, thanks for sharing this :) This seems like the right answer now

Comment: Now, 4 years after this answer was wrote, `django-overextends` is not needed anymore. [See the docs](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.11.3/advanced_topics/customisation/admin_templates.html)

Comment: @YasielCabrera thanks for sharing. Would you please add it as a Note at the beginning of the response, I will approve it.

Answer (score 9):

The logo is defined here:

https://github.com/torchbox/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/wagtailadmin/templates/wagtailadmin/base.html#L7

To override it, you'll need an app which contains `templates/wagtailadmin/base.html` and precedes wagtail in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks!, I didn't know I needed to have my app in front of others to override templates, very useful. I just found that when using `TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates'),)` in settings, templates placed in this directory also overrides other apps so no need to mess with app order :)

Comment: A more in-depth explanation can be found in the current wagtail documentation (http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.0b1/howto/custom_branding.html). Also, *django-overextends* is a great way to override 3rd-party templates cleanly.