# Why django staticfiles serving svg as application/octet-stream instead of image/svg+xml

Tags: django, svg, mime-types

I used [wagtail-generator](http://wagtail.io/) with `yoeman` to generate a [wagtail](https://www.npmjs.org/package/generator-wagtail) django project and svg files served by django with `django.contrib.staticfiles` output `application/octet-stream` mimetype instead of `image/svg+xml` mimetype which breaks picture rendering.

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2313050/1092815) without success but I'm sure that using something like `nginx` to serve static files would fix this (did not try yet).

Based [on this answer to another of my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24536034/how-to-change-django-wagtails-admin-logo), I can copy wagtail's template in my templates so I can change the admin logo, but it doesn't fix the svg problem ;)

What I'm getting right now:

[image: wagtail with broken svg logo]

And here's the response from Chrome network tab in case it could help:

[image: Chrome network tab]

```
$ wget http://localhost:8000/static/wagtailadmin/images/wagtail-logo.svg
```

output:

```
--2014-07-02 16:14:36--  http://localhost:8000/static/wagtailadmin/images/wagtail-logo.svg
Resolving localhost... 127.0.0.1, ::1, fe80::1
Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:8000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3082 (3.0K) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: 'wagtail-logo.svg'

100%[=============================================================>] 3,082       --.-K/s   in 0.006s

2014-07-02 16:14:36 (466 KB/s) - 'wagtail-logo.svg' saved [3082/3082]
```

Comment: We faced this issue yesterday - The issue is, your nginx configuration needs to set the right mime-type for SVG (If not specified as an image type, it takes it as an octet stream.) Hence the issue - To verify, curl the image in verbose mode and see the mime-type

Comment: I did not try to serve static files with nginx yet (I supposed it should work fine with nginx), problem is with static files being served *by django*, I just edited my question to add `wget` output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the Django dev server correctly serve SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312714/can-the-django-dev-server-correctly-serve-svg)

Comment: facing the same issue with django 1.11